# vsTestHost.exe uses only one processor

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vstesthost

I have a simple load test that is using one TestMethod on a quad core 64 bit windows 2008 box.

When i run the load test, i only see one processor being used to 100%, other processors are just idle, and i know that the server is not being hit to the max, so my test agent is not able to produce enough load for it.

is there any way to tell it to use multiple processors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ashish,

Microsoft purposefully limits vsTestHost.exe to use only 1 core.  I know of no way to get it to use multiple cores.

This is a "bait-and-switch" tactic that Microsoft uses so very often.  They want you to purchase separate licenses for their Test Load Agent software.  The Test Load Agent software/process is multi-threaded, and will run across all cores of a CPU.

Regards,

Brent